# Getting limited user input, with echo

Tags: c++, strings, windows, console

I've written a code snippet that will get a (max.) 14 character string from the user input, and while the user is typing, simultaneously echo it out to the screen.

It seems a bit long and ugly, so I was wondering if any of you would happen to have ideas on how to shorten, and generally optimize this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    char npt = _getch(); // Get input

    if(i == 14) // Last character (user has to press \r or \b)
    {
        if(npt == '\r') // enter, break loop
            break;
        else if(npt == '\b') // backspace, re-loop
        {
            if(!name.empty())
                name.erase(std::prev(name.end()));
            if(i >= 1)
                i -= 2;
            else
                i--;
        }
        else // other input, meaning re-loop
            i--;

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cDraw);
        printf("              "); // clear string area
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cDraw);
        std::cout << name; // echo string
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        if(npt == '\r')
            break;
        else if(npt == '\b')
        {
            if(!name.empty())
                name.erase(std::prev(name.end()));
            if(i >= 1)
                i -= 2;
            else
                i--;
        }
        else
            name += npt; // add input to string

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cDraw);
        printf("              ");
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cDraw);
        std::cout << name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c++ isn't really my language, but I believe this would be an identical loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  char npt = _getch(); // Get input

  if(npt == '\r')
    break;
  else if(npt == '\b')
  {
    if(!name.empty())
      name.erase(std::prev(name.end()));
    if(i >= 1)
      i -= 2;
    else
      i--;
  }
  else if(i == 14)
    i--;
  else            
    name += npt; // add input to string

  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cDraw);
  printf("              ");
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, cDraw);
  std::cout << name;
}
```

The only difference between your first `if` and the `else` is the final `else` line, so I moved the conditional to the end to avoid repeating the same logic.

Additionally, I assume there's some way you could pad `name` with blank spaces so that you only have to call `SetConsoleCursorPosition` and print once per iteration.

Comment: Hey, that's a really good answer! I'll accept it in a minute. Meanwhile, would you have an idea on how to efficiently do the `name` padding?

Comment: I don't know. But [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/15952/) seems to provide a possible method. You might ask on StackOverflow if you're unable to find a way after searching.

Comment: Ok, I'll search around for an answer. Thanks, man.